# Split dictionary into multiple dictionaries by indices of one of dictionary's value

Tags: python

What would be an elegant and efficient way to split the `data` dictionary into as many dictionaries as there are unique values in `data['legend']`, each dictionary representing a legend entry? All lists will always be in proper order.

I am currentling using the below, but am interested if there is a shorter solution:

```
data = {
    'x':  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
    'legend': ["active", "pending", "pending", "active", "completed", "pending", "pending","active", "completed", "active"],
    };

traces = [] 
unique_legend = list(set(data['legend']))
for item in unique_legend:
    trace = {}
    item_indices = [k for k,v in enumerate(data['legend']) if v == item]
    trace['x'] = [data['x'][indice] for indice in item_indices]
    trace['y'] = [data['y'][indice] for indice in item_indices]
    traces.append(trace)

for trace in traces:
    print(trace)
```

Comment: is the dictionary's purpose to display all (x, y) of a particular legend status (active)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way I might approach it:

```
result = {}
for x in zip(data['x'], data['y'], data['legend']):
    result.setdefault(x[2], []).append(x[:2])

# result will look like the following:
# {
#    'active': [(1, 10), (4, 40), (8, 80), ...],
#    ...
# }
```

Answer (score 1):

I invite you to meet `pandas`, which simplify such frequent needs :

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(data).set_index("legend").sort_index()
print(df)
            x    y
legend            
active      1   10
active      4   40
active      8   80
active     10  100
completed   5   50
completed   9   90
pending     2   20
pending     3   30
pending     6   60
pending     7   70
```

Then it's easy to access all sub parts :

```
>>> df.loc['active','x']

legend
active     1
active     4
active     8
active    10
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

You can come back to a more familiar form :

```
>>> { leg:{ key:list(df.loc[leg,key]) for key in df.columns} for leg in df.index.unique()}  

{'active': {'x': [1, 4, 8, 10], 'y': [10, 40, 80, 100]},
 'completed': {'x': [5, 9], 'y': [50, 90]},
 'pending': {'x': [2, 3, 6, 7], 'y': [20, 30, 60, 70]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, it looks like you are trying to get `list`s of `x` and `y` corresponding to a `legend` entry. You can do that using `zip` to collect everything together. Note, this will require `len(x)==len(y)==len(legend)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

triples = zip(data['legend'], data['x'], data['y'])
trace = defaultdict(list)

for legend, x, y in triples:
    trace[legend].append((x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple

dtype = namedtuple('dtype', ['legend', 'x', 'y'])
sorted_legends = sorted((dtype(*l) for l in zip(data['legend'], data['x'], 
    data['y'])))

for k,v in groupby(sorted_legends, key=lambda x:x.legend):
    x, y = [], []
    for i in v:
        x.append(i[1])
        y.append(i[2])
    print({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

I've used a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which is really great fro maintainable code(might be a bit of and overkill for your request).